# Unity que no muestra sprite

Tags: unity

Acabo de empezar con Unity y recién aprendí a importar assets. Ahora no se muestran las figuras de un sprite, le doy clic a la flechita y solo aparece una copia del mismo, no el resto de las imágenes. !!!

[image: Mi escena vacia, tratando de colocar una de las figuras del sprite]

Answer (score 1):

- Sprite mode -> Multiple -> hacemos clic en Sprite Editor y le damos a aplicar.
- Se abre el editor con la imagen seleccionada, hacemos clic en la pestañita que dice Slice y se abre un diálogo
- Dejar el Type de Slice como Automatic. asi se marcan todas las imágenes, le damos a aceptar o aplicar y listo !

Comment: Claro que puedes dejar el enlace como referencia